# Facebook Open Graph locale for Australia

Tags: facebook, internationalization, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to add the og:locale tag for an Australian website and Facebook's linter tells me that I have an error.

Based on the documentation (and assuming what the correct content should be), I have added this to my page head:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_AU" />
```

Facebook's linter ( http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug ) tells me:

Object Invalid Value
Object at URL 'http://foo' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value 'en_au' for property 'og:locale:locale' could not be parsed as type 'enum'.

What's going on here? Is en_AU not the correct code for australia? I also tried en_AUS and that didn't work either. If i change it to en_US it works fine.

Comment: Does this error affect your standing within the Open Graph or on Facebook? As far as I can tell it reports the error but falls back to the default internally. (never the less, I've changed it on my project)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

See FB's [i18n documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization) for help. More specifically there is a complete list of [supported locales](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/supported-locales/). Unfortunately Australian English isn't awesome enough to be considered as a separate thing; you'll be choosing between UK and US English.

Comment: Thanks Ben; looks like that's the problem; and I was looking for a supported list too, Cheers

Comment: Australian English's awesomeness isn't in question.

Comment: AU english is very close to UK english, so best choice would be en_GB